# zlib not found error by PyQT5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, zlib

I have built an interface that includes a web browser and it throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interface.py", line 719, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWebKitWidgets
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /home/user/.conda/envs/mp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/../../.././libpng16.so.16)
```

I ran

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

and got

```
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version (1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1).
```

So it seems QT5 needs version 1.2.9 and I have 1.2.8 . I am on ubuntu 16.04, any ideas how I can get the newer version?

EDIT: I used [THIS](https://geeksww.com/tutorials/libraries/zlib/installation/installing_zlib_on_ubuntu_linux.php) to install zlib 1.2.11, still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download source code of needed version and build it.

[zlib 1.2.9](https://zlib.net/fossils/zlib-1.2.9.tar.gz)

Download and extract archive. `cd` to extracted directory and run `./configure`, then run `make`
After you can see file `libz.so.1`, move it to the `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

For those who can't get this problem solved with phoenix76's solution, try the following (original post from https://askubuntu.com/a/1169769/516320):

You need to install *-dev* package for `zlib1g` - it is named [`zlib1g-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/zlib1g-dev):

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

and it will install `zlib.pc` file for `pkg-config` [along with *zlib.h* header](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/zlib1g-dev/filelist).